# Material-UI: Display TextField with labelWidth = 0

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to display such a field

[image]

But even when the field is in focus the border remains intact and is not cut by the label

[image]

I am using material-UI TextField

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to float the label right, use `text-align: right`.

Comment: I want the border to remain intact even when the field is in focus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to:

- hide the label (I am doing it when you enter a value just to show you - you can remove it altogether if you'd like)
- complete the border i.e. remove the legend (CSS)

relevant **CSS**:

```
legend { border:1px solid red; display:none; }
```

relevant **js**:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  cssLabel: {
    color: "green"
  },

  cssLabelHide: {
    display: "none"
  },
});

<TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={this.state.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange("name")}
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined"
        InputLabelProps={{
          classes: {
            root:
              this.state.labelVisibility === true
                ? classes.cssLabel
                : classes.cssLabelHide,
            focused: classes.cssFocused
          }
        }}
        InputProps={{
          classes: {
            root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
            focused: classes.cssFocused,
            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
          },
          inputMode: "numeric"
        }}
      />
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-custom-outline-color-s9nkiu)

Comment: Thank you for your help
Is it possible to not see the label at all
When the field is in focus

Comment: just replace `this.state.labelVisibility === true
                ? classes.cssLabel
                : classes.cssLabelHide` with `classes.cssLabelHide` and you’ll get what you want

Comment: I need a label to appear but after the field is in focus it will not appear

Comment: label to appear where at the top (cutting the border) ?